# PDO PHP Insert Trouble, No Errors

Tags: php, runtime-error

I am not getting any errors. I cleared the error php_error_log file, ran the script, no errors. Its suppose to insert into a table, but it doesnt. Here is the code.

Thanks for any help that i get, i am just tired of not knowing why this sint working. No errors, no output, but not modifying the table.

PS- Yes i did declare the db and etc, its just now shown.

```html
stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,email) VALUES(NULL,:username,:password,:first_name,:last_name,:email)");
$stmt->execute(array('username' => $sec_user, 'password' => $sec_pass, 'first_name' => $sec_first, 'last_name' => $sec_last, 'email' => $sec_email));
        if ($stmt) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$db->insert_id;
            echo "<p>You are now registered. You will be redirected in 5 seconds, or click Login below.</p>";
            header("refresh:5;url=http://scrubhost.servehttp.com/login.php");
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$db->getMessage} : {$db->getMessage}</p>";
            exit();
        }
```

I also have tried

```html
    $resultprep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES ( '?','?','?','?','?')");
$resultprep->bindParam(1, $sec_usere, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultprep->bindParam(2, $sec_passe, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultprep->bindParam(3, $sec_firste, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultprep->bindParam(4, $sec_laste, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultprep->bindParam(5, $sec_emaile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $resultprep->execute(); 
  if ($resultprep) {
}
```

Along with the array method that uses "?"'s

--edit

```html
try { 

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,email) VALUES(NULL,:username,:password,:first_name,:last_name,:email)");
$stmt->execute(array('username' => $sec_user, 'password' => $sec_pass, 'first_name' => $sec_first, 'last_name' => $sec_last, 'email' => $sec_email));
        if ($stmt) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$db->insert_id;
            echo "<p>You are now registered. You will be redirected in 5 seconds, or click Login below.</p>";
            header("refresh:5;url=http://scrubhost.servehttp.com/login.php");
        } else {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$db->getMessage} : {$db->getMessage}</p>";
            exit();
        }

} catch(PDOException $e){ $e->getMessage(); }
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php

$iv = '1928705354837653';


$encrypt_key = '8913f09a87A098F7YA90D8FTAG97RGA[W9UHDASOIJHASDIJSGADIUGashfaouihfadfdaf1ad56';



   function pkcs7_pad($data, $size)
   {
       $length = $size - strlen($data) % $size;
       return $data . str_repeat(chr($length), $length);
   }
   function pkcs7_unpad($data)
   {
       return substr($data, 0, -ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]));
   }
    


?>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>RSPS Host - Register</title>

    <link href="/ucp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="gray-bg">
    <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen   animated fadeInDown">
        <div>
            <div>

                <h1 class="logo-name"> </h1>

            </div>
            <h3>Register</h3>
<?php
require_once("db_const.php");
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>  <!-- The HTML registration form -->
<body class="gray-bg">
            <p>Please fill out all fields. </p>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <form class="m-t" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input type="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="">
                    <input type="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>
    </form>
                    <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>
<?php
} else {
## connect mysql server
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mainrspshosts', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->beginTransaction();
## query database
    # prepare data for insertion
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];

    $encryption_key_user  = $encrypt_key . $username;
    $encryption_key_pass = $encrypt_key . $password;
    $encryption_key_firstname  = $encrypt_key . $first_name;
    $encryption_key_lastname = $encrypt_key . $last_name;
    $encryption_key_email = $encrypt_key . $email;

     $sec_user = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($username, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_pass,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_pass = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($password, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_pass,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_first = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($first_name, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_firstname,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_last = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($last_name, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_lastname,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_email = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($email, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_email,
         0,
         $iv
     );

    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $exists = 0;
    $resultprep = $db->prepare("SELECT username from users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
     $resultprep->execute(array($sec_user)); 
     $result = $resultprep->fetchAll();
    if (count($result) == 1) {
        $exists = 1;
        $resultprepare = $db->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '?' LIMIT 1");
            
     $resultprep->execute(array($sec_email)); 
     $result = $resultprep->fetchAll();
        if (count($result)     == 1) $exists = 2;   
    } else {
        $resultprep = $db->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '?' LIMIT 1");
            
     $resultprep->execute(array($sec_email)); 
     $result = $resultprep->fetchAll();
        if (count($result)     == 1) $exists = 3;
    }
 
    if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
        # insert data into mysql database
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);// turn on error reporting by placing this on top
$resultprep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`password`) VALUES ('test')");
$resultprep->execute(); 
if ($resultprep) {
            //echo "New Record has id ".$db->insert_id;
            echo "<p>You are now registered. You will be redirected in 5 seconds, or click Login below.</p>";
            header("refresh:5;url=http://scrubhost.servehttp.com/login.php");
        } else {

            exit();
        }


    }
}
?>      

                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.php">Login</a>
            </form>
            <p class="m-t">  Copyright <strong>RSPSHost.info</strong> &copy; 2015 - 2016
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mainly scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes for these `( '?','?','?','?','?')`

Comment: Is the insert query working when you manually do it in phpmyadmin or MySQL console.If id is Auto Increment then no need to include it in the columns field

Comment: Plus, you're technically missing a `$` in `stmt = $db->prepare` unless that's just a bad paste.

Comment: Add `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Also use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - You should also use a try/catch.

Comment: if($stmt->rowCount()>0) would be better it shows the number of rows affected by a Query.

Comment: Then I see `$sec_user` and `$sec_usere` so which one is correct and where are those being assigned as? Check for errors. Error checking/reporting will tell you. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yes it works if i manually enter it. @AAB

Comment: Fred, yeah it was a bad paste

Comment: Fred ,I already had that line of code right after it, and why should i use a try and catch @Fred-ii-

Comment: `$db->getMessage` you forgot the `()` in there. Yes, `try {
// query
}
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getMessage();
    }`

Comment: I just edited in what i have, and it didtn work, is it suppose to output something?

Comment: @DamienOstler might sound weird but try inserting for one column value what I mean is table(col1) VALUES(val1) then try table(col1,col2) VALUES(val1,val2) then so on I had a similar issue and well for some reason the insert failed when I included a column named appl_year.I solved the issue by dropping and re creating the column with same name

Comment: Go over all the comments again and the first one too with the quotes around the `?` they can't be in there. If you can successfully use a hard-coded value, then your variables are failing you somewhere. Error reporting set to ON and to "display" will tell you that, including exceptions.

Comment: How do i turn error reporting on and to display? Is that in the php.ini or something?

Comment: Like this => [Posted 7 mins. ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479288/pdo-php-insert-trouble-no-errors#comment47119248_29479288) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479288/pdo-php-insert-trouble-no-errors#comment47119183_29479288)

Comment: @AAB doesnt work, tried it with all the collumns, and just inseting "test" instead of a variable. Its just nto working at all.

Comment: put the entire page in at the end of my post, if anyone still wants to help

Answer (score 0):

In your database `id` should be auto incerment and probably a primary key.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);// turn on error reporting by placing this on top
$resultprep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES (:username,:password,:first_name,:last_name,:email)");
$resultprep->bindParam(:username, $sec_usere);
$resultprep->bindParam(:password, $sec_passe);
$resultprep->bindParam(:first_name, $sec_firste);
$resultprep->bindParam(:last_name, $sec_laste);
$resultprep->bindParam(:email, $sec_emaile);
$resultprep->execute(); 
if ($resultprep) {
}
```

your complete code

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);// turn on error reporting by placing this on top
 //require_once("db_const.php");
  try {
  $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mainrspshosts', 'root', ''); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  $db->rollBack();
}
$iv = '1928705354837653';
$encrypt_key = '8913f09a87A098F7YA90D8FTAG97RGA[W9UHDASOIJHASDIJSGADIUGashfaouihfadfdaf1ad56';

   function pkcs7_pad($data, $size)
   {
       $length = $size - strlen($data) % $size;
       return $data . str_repeat(chr($length), $length);
   }
   function pkcs7_unpad($data)
   {
       return substr($data, 0, -ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]));
   }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
    # prepare data for insertion
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $password   = $_POST['password'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];

    $encryption_key_user  = $encrypt_key . $username;
    $encryption_key_pass = $encrypt_key . $password;
    $encryption_key_firstname  = $encrypt_key . $first_name;
    $encryption_key_lastname = $encrypt_key . $last_name;
    $encryption_key_email = $encrypt_key . $email;

     $sec_user = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($username, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_pass,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_pass = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($password, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_pass,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_first = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($first_name, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_firstname,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_last = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($last_name, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_lastname,
         0,
         $iv
     );
     $sec_email = openssl_encrypt(
         pkcs7_pad($email, 16),
         'AES-256-CBC',
         $encryption_key_email,
         0,
         $iv
     );

    # check if username and email exist else insert
    $resultprep = $db->prepare("SELECT `username`,`email` from `users` WHERE `username` = :username OR `email`=:email");
     $resultprep->bindParam(:username,$sec_user);
     $resultprep->bindParam(:email,$sec_email);
     $resultprep->execute(); 
     $error=0;
     while($result = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($sec_user == $result['username']) {
    echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    $error=1;
    }
    if ($sec_email == $result['email']) {
    echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    $error=1;
    }
    if ($sec_user == $result['username'] && $sec_email == $result['email']) {
    $error=1;
    echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    }
}
# insert data into mysql database
if($error!=0) {
$resultprep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES (:username, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :email)");
$resultprep->bindParam(:username, $sec_user);
$resultprep->bindParam(:password, $sec_pass);
$resultprep->bindParam(:first_name, $sec_first);
$resultprep->bindParam(:last_name, $sec_last);
$resultprep->bindParam(:email, $sec_email);
$resultprep->execute(); 
if ($resultprep) {
            echo "<p>You are now registered. You will be redirected in 5 seconds, or click Login below.</p>";
            header("refresh:5;url=http://scrubhost.servehttp.com/login.php");
        } else {
            exit();
        }  
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>RSPS Host - Register</title>

    <link href="/ucp/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/ucp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="gray-bg">
    <div class="middle-box text-center loginscreen   animated fadeInDown">
        <div>
            <div>

                <h1 class="logo-name"> </h1>

            </div>
            <h3>Register</h3>

<body class="gray-bg">
            <p>Please fill out all fields. </p>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
            <form class="m-t" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                    <input type="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required="">
                    <input type="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required="">
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Register</button>
    </form>
                    <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Already have an account?</small></p>    

                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="login.php">Login</a>
            </form>
            <p class="m-t">  Copyright <strong>RSPSHost.info</strong> &copy; 2015 - 2016
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Mainly scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.i-checks').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Using the column for the id and NULL as a value should be fine.

Comment: Sure same thing also if you make it Auto-Increment and not include it in the insert at all.

Comment: Yeah i was going to do that later, im new to php and started doing thaht later, im just going through all my code and making it more secure now..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply, yeah i tried it, edited the variables cause i made a typo in the paste, but yeah, it doesnt work :/

Comment: Can you post your PDO-MySQL db connection code? or more of your php code in general, MySQL server is running? :)

Comment: What is db_const.php ?

Comment: was originally the place where db info was saved. :P But like i said, im  reoding sql stuff for security reasons

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 75"
Shouldnt the :username and etc be in quotations or something?

Comment: Fixed that but now i have "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch() in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 80"

Comment: Sorry i have edited my code i have forgotten $db->fetchAll code line before the while loop that's why it was producing the error.